# Cannot find a way to load a custom xkb keymap on login in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have made a custom xkb keymap that I am happy with, and I can load it with no issues using the following script

`xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykeys $DISPLAY`

and it works the way I want when I do it manually.

My problem is, I could not find any reasonable place to put it where it could be run on login and NOT get overwritten by the default configuration.
I have tried `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsession`, `~/.xsessionrc`, `~/.xprofile`, even `~/.config/autostart-scripts`

Most of those scripts are run (checked with `zenity`), but it looks like something downstream apparently reverts back to the default configuration later, so that when my KDE plasma loads, the keys I remapped do not work until I run this script again manually.

How could I fix this?

UPDATE: I also noticed that I need to re-run the script after the laptop wakes up from sleep. Is there a way to make it more permanent without modifying the default config in /usr/share/X11/xkb ?

UPDATE 2: When the laptop wakes up from sleep, my keys are actually still working for about 2-3 seconds, and then suddenly stop (around the same time my bluetooth mouse reconnects: not sure whether this could be related or not) until I re-run the script.

UPDATE 3: Here's the contents of `~/.xkb/keymap/mykeys` :

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+mysymbols(super_arrows)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

and this is `~/.xkb/symbols/mysymbols`:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "super_arrows" {
    key <LEFT>  {
        type = "PC_SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Left,   Home      ],
        actions[Group1] = [    NoAction(),  RedirectKey(keycode=<HOME>, clearmods=Mod4) ]
    };
    key <RGHT>  {
        type = "PC_SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Right,  End       ],
        actions[Group1] = [    NoAction(),  RedirectKey(keycode=<END>, clearmods=Mod4) ]
    };
    key <UP>  {
        type = "PC_SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Up,  Prior       ],
        actions[Group1] = [    NoAction(),  RedirectKey(keycode=<PGUP>, clearmods=Mod4) ]
    };
    key <DOWN>  {
        type = "PC_SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Down,  Next       ],
        actions[Group1] = [    NoAction(),  RedirectKey(keycode=<PGDN>, clearmods=Mod4) ]
    };
    key <INS> {
        symbols[Group1] = [    Print             ],
        actions[Group1] = [    RedirectKey(keycode=<PRSC>) ]
    };
};
```

If I put `include "mysymbols(super_arrows)"` into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`, and a symlink to mysymbols into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, then my config becomes stable, but after re-login the redefined keys seize to auto-repeat (when pressed and held).
So my current process is: after login:

- launch `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykeys $DISPLAY` manually
- uncomment `include "mysymbols(super_arrows)"` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`
  Then I can use the config normally until the next restart (re-login) :)
  Linux is really full of magic ! ;)

Comment: Same problem for me :  I had a working file loaded with kubuntu 18.04 and xkbcomp but with kubuntu 20.04 `xkbcomp ~/.xkbfrperso.xkb "$DISPLAY"` does only work in a terminal for the current session and I don't know how to pus this command line.

Answer (score -2):

This is explained (for another layout, but you'll find your way) at the bottom of this [page](https://www.choam.eu/altgr-intl/).

Comment: I don't see how that page is relevant to my question. It is all about modifying stuff in `/usr/share/X11/xkb` which works, but has some other undesirable side effects in my case (e.g. redefined keys do not repeat anymore). My question was actually: how to prevent KDE from automatically re-reading the configuration from `/usr/share/X11/xkb` from time to time, and instead keep on using the one I load with `xkbcomp` manually

Comment: Without the contents of your 'mykeys' file and the constraint that you do not want to change `/usr/share/X11/xkb`... makes it difficult (for me to help you). You mention `~/.config/autostart-scripts` (which my system does not have). Maybe you meant `~/.config/autostart` - in that case the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170947/1127942) that @Evgeni Sergeev gave may be useful for you

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I tried the recipe in @Evgeni Sergeev 's answer, but it didn't work for me. KDE is still re-reading the config from `/usr/share/X11/xkb` *after* it executes all autostart scripts. 
I put the contents of all my scripts in UPDATE 3 to my question above. The constraint not to change `/usr/share/X11/xkb` is not that important for me, but, as I mentioned, it has side effects for some reason: the redefined keys stop repeating. I don't see this problem if I launch the script manually after login.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain what your intention is with `super_arrows`? Do you want (for example) DOWN to function as PGDN when pressed with SUPER? You may have a conflicting definition that happens to work when invoked 'manually' but gets reset after `/usr/share/X11/xkb` is re-read.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I want to achieve. I am a "lucky" owner of one of those Dell laptops, whose "ingenious" designers have decided that users don't need Home and End keys on Fn+Left and Fn+Right anymore. Those combinations do not generate any keyboard events at all. So substituting Fn with Super is an attempt to restore some reasonable level of productivity.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the keys might stop repeating when redefined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`?

Comment: I suspect the RedirectKey, but I cannot find a confirmation. I'm working on another solution but I lack the time to test it (and my daily keyboard does not have a SUPER key - must get the laptop first). I'll get back to this.

Comment: My idea was to use level5 as a modifier for the arrow keys. In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`, I changed the UP key into: `key <UP> { type="EIGHT_LEVEL", [ Up, Up, Prior, Prior, Prior ] };` And the other keys similarly. Then, I chose the Super key to be Level5Shift (`include "level5(lwin_switch_lock)"` in the current keymap). It looks promising, but breaks some other stuff... The `Prior` in level 3 and 4 make it work with AltGr (which is Level4Shift on my keyboards). No solution as you wanted. Sorry.